# If first function is correct, got stuck in the simple situation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that my question is obviously ordinary, but I'm a bit newbie and dunno how *shortly* and, what most important, *correctly* perform that.
So, I've got something like this:

```
 $('button').on('click', func1).on('click', func2);
```

As you can see I've got 2 'click' events on the same button, but `func2` must execute **only** if `func1` is correct. Dunno how properly write `if` statement here, any valuable help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct'? It would be best in this case to call `func2` from `func1` when the conditions are as you require.

Comment: you want if first function is have condition, if  its get tru you have to trigger second click right

Comment: You don't have two events, you have two listeners for a click event

Comment: You should pass your second function as an argument to your first function and execute it after ur first function is completed.

Comment: VisioN've already asked my simple question, thx to all anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, and on `click` event you want to execute `func2` only if `func1` returns non-falsey value, then why not to transform it to:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    func1() && func2();

    // same as:
    // if (func1())
    //     func2();
});
```